# How to use SendGrid from Google App Engine Golang?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, sendgrid, urlfetch, sendgrid-api-v3

The example code at: https://sendgrid.com/blog/send-email-go-google-app-engine/

My guess this is very old sample code to use sendgrid-go on Google App Engine.

I've attempted 4 permutations and failed each time with:

```
https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send: http.DefaultTransport and http.DefaultClient are not available in App Engine. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/urlfetch/
```

Here is a minimum hardcoded attempt with some logging:

```
package sendgridgo


import(
    "github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-go"
    "fmt"
    _"google.golang.org/appengine"
    "net/http"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/log"
    "google.golang.org/appengine"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/urlfetch"
     _ "github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-go/helpers/mail"
)

func init(){
    http.HandleFunc("/", IndexHandler)
    appengine.Main()
}

func IndexHandler (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)

    log.Infof(ctx, "IndexHandler")
    sg := sendgrid.NewSendClient("SENDGRID_API_KEY")
    log.Infof(ctx, "%v", sg)
    bob := urlfetch.Client(ctx)

    log.Infof(ctx, "UrlFetchClient %v", bob)
    //resp, err := sg.Send(m)
    request := sendgrid.GetRequest("SENDGRID_API_KEY", "/v3/mail/send", "https://api.sendgrid.com")
    request.Method = "POST"

    request.Body = []byte(` {
    "personalizations": [
        {
            "to": [
                {
                    "email": "darian.hickman@gmail.com"
                }
            ],
            "subject": "Sending with SendGrid is Fun"
        }
    ],
    "from": {
        "email": "darian.hickman@villagethegame.com"
    },
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "text/plain",
            "value": "and easy to do anywhere, even with Go"
        }
    ]
}`)
    resp, err := sendgrid.API(request)

    if err != nil{
        log.Errorf(ctx, "Failed %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Fprint(w, resp)


}
```

Comment: Refrain from sharing your API Key in public.

Comment: The v3 package has a `DefaultClient` variable. Did you try setting that to `bob`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 8 different attempts, including trying an example published in Google Cloud docs for using Sendgrid, an example from Sendgrid blog, and trying to use deprecated versions of Sendgrid api, I found Sendgrid curl examples at:

https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/v3_Mail_Send/curl_examples.html

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "recipient@example.com"}]}],"from": {"email": "sendeexampexample@example.com"},"subject": "Hello, World!","content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "Heya!"}]}'
```

I then translated the HelloWorld example to into URLFetch usage

```
client := urlfetch.Client(ctx)

request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send", buf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf(ctx, "Failed Request %v", request)
    }
    request.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer SENDGRID_API_KEY")
    request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    resp, err := client.Do(request)
```

One Easter weekend, later, it works!

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track, but skipped overriding the default `sendgrid` client with `urlfetch` client.

```
.
.
.
func IndexHandler (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)    
    sg := sendgrid.NewSendClient("REPLACE_WITH_API_KEY")
    bob := urlfetch.Client(ctx)

    sg.Client = bob

    request := sendgrid.GetRequest("REPLACE_WITH_API_KEY", "/v3/mail/send", "https://api.sendgrid.com")
    request.Method = "POST"
.
.
.
```

**Explanation**

The error occurs as sendgrid tries to fetch a url with the default `net/http` method.

Quoting AppEngine Documentation

> App Engine uses the URL Fetch service to issue outbound HTTP(S) requests. To issue an outbound HTTP request, use the http package as usual, but create your client using urlfetch.Client. urlfetch.Client returns an *http.Client that uses urlfetch.Transport, which is an implementation of the http.RoundTripper interface that makes requests using the URL Fetch API.

The workaround is to override the Sendgrid client to use `urlfetch`

```
        context := appengine.NewContext(r)
        sg := sendgrid.NewSendClient(os.Getenv("SENDGRID_API_KEY"))
        sg.Client = urlfetch.Client(context)
```

References

1. [GCloud Documentation- Issuing HTTP(S) Requests in App Engine Golang](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/issue-requests)

Comment: Great answer, I upvoted it. It's worth noting that GAE has a lot of limitation (the GAE sandbox) on what can be done on it and our URLFetch method is basically there to make sure we don't need to expose the native net/http method to users.

Comment: The latest sendgrid-go package version doesn't have sg.Client.  It won't even compile.   I tried a few different workarounds on that and gave up.

Comment: When I found the import statement to use the old Sendgrid v2 api :  "gopkg.in/sendgrid/sendgrid-go.v2", I got it to compile and run, but sendgrid returns bad username / pass on every attempt.  Buried somewhere in their docs is: "You can't use API keys with anything older than v3".

Comment: @Darian311 From the docs on the github page for v2, it says you'd need to use `sendgrid.NewSendGridClientWithApiKey` instead of `sendgrid.NewSendGridClient` if you're using an api key.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is documented in **sendgrid.go**:

```
// DefaultClient is used if no custom HTTP client is defined
var DefaultClient = rest.DefaultClient
```

So just do this at the beginning of your send, where **ctx** is **appengine.NewContext(req)**:

```
sendgrid.DefaultClient = &rest.Client{HTTPClient: urlfetch.Client(ctx)}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, using go 1.11 on Google App Angine Standard, with the latest example from sendgrid's go library v3 example on github.   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**SendGrid** document the minimum needed code to send an email with Go on AppEngine in
[How to send email using Go](https://app.sendgrid.com/guide/integrate/langs/go). It differs from @birju-prajapati's answer; the client is created with `sendgrid.NewSendClient`.

An API key must be generated and your development environment updated with your `SENDGRID_API_KEY`.  Then install **sendgrid-go** and its dependencies with `go get github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-go`.

```golang
// using SendGrid's Go Library
// https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-go"
    "github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-go/helpers/mail"
)

func main() {
    from := mail.NewEmail("Example User", "test@example.com")
    subject := "Sending with SendGrid is Fun"
    to := mail.NewEmail("Example User", "test@example.com")
    plainTextContent := "and easy to do anywhere, even with Go"
    htmlContent := "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Go</strong>"
    message := mail.NewSingleEmail(from, subject, to, plainTextContent, htmlContent)
    client := sendgrid.NewSendClient(os.Getenv("SENDGRID_API_KEY"))
    response, err := client.Send(message)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(response.StatusCode)
        fmt.Println(response.Body)
        fmt.Println(response.Headers)
    }
}
```